# Android Market- Number of Active installs exceeds total downloads

Tags: android, google-play

[image: Number of Active installs exceeds total downloads]

I am wondering how the active installs exceeds the total installs. I suspect some one copied the app and installed on another phone...Can anyone post if it is possible some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The market statistics are by no means perfect.  They are only periodically updated, and have frequently bounced around like crazy.  When I first published an app it was actually double counting one of the stats - Google fixed the bug that caused that but didn't fix the statistics.

I've also seen people report issues with paid application statistics being inaccurate where people click to buy and the download doesn't go through, or they cancel inside the 15 min window etc..

They constantly tweek the basis for the calculation as well - with a change as recent as May 2nd

> As of May 2, 2011, we’ve changed the
>   basis for calculation of install
>   numbers provided in the Android Market
>   Developer Console. Previously, app
>   installs were calculated per user and
>   did not account for certain uninstall
>   activities (like when a device was
>   factory reset). Installs are now
>   counted per device, with duplicates
>   more effectively filtered out. This
>   offers you a more accurate measure of
>   your app distribution in the Android
>   ecosystem.
>
> You may notice that this change has
>   resulted in a one-time decrease in the
>   number of total installs for your
>   apps. We apologize for any confusion
>   this may have caused

Basically there a lots of bugs with the way they track the stats so don't trust 'em.